# AngularJS : Why to check whether newValue is the same as oldValue in `$watch` listener?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I saw the pattern below many times:

```
$scope.$watch('full_name', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {

 if(newVal === oldVal) {
   return
 } else {
 }
}
```

I don't quite understand the `if(newVal==oldVal)` branch because it looks useless.. Shouldn't the listener callback function only be called when the watched value is changed? If that is the case, shouldn't `newVal` always be different from  `oldVal`?
If not, does anyone have examples about what can be done in the `newVal==oldVal` branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if (newVal === oldVal)` construct is to skip initialisation. AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) states that when you attach the watch, it will call the callback once with `undefined, undefined`. To prevent your watch function from mistaking this call for a model change, you can add the `if` construct.

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.